# Is that possible upload file when i m click on browse button in plupload?

Tags: plupload

In custom api

```
  <div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5     support.</div>
<div width="20px" id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="container">
  <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a> 
  <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
</div>
```

In this when we click on Upload files that time file is upload bt i want when i am click Select files that time also upload file. so what changes i have to do in my script if possible?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // Custom example logic
  var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({

//runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
url : 'upload.php',


filters : {
    max_file_size : '100mb',
    mime_types: [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
    ]
},

init: {
    PostInit: function() {
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
            uploader.start();
            return false;
        };


    },
    FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
        plupload.each(files, function(file) {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div><br/>';

        });
    },
    UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
        document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: false
        });

    },
      UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: true
            });
        },

    Error: function(up, err) {
        document.getElementById('console').appendChild(document.createTextNode("Error #" + err.code + ": " + err.message +"\n"));
    }
}
});
uploader.init();

</script>
```

please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this in the `FilesAdded` event.

Try this:

```
FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
    plupload.each(files, function(file) {
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div><br/>';

    });
    up.start();
},
```